# Connecting to Sphero sprk+ android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, sphero-api, sphero

I am trying to connect my Android App to Sphero Sprk+ . The Sphero-SDK comes with samples to connect to sphero robot. I have tried that but could not connect to the sprk+. The reason I think is that SPRK+ requires proximity detection profile for Bluetooth LE (4.0 and onwards). Is there a hack or source code that connects to sprk+ ? I tried the Android's Bluetooth LE sample code for the heart rate monitoring profile , and I was able to detect and connect to the SPRK+ . But being a newbie , I still am looking to understand if the sprk+ is a GATT server or GATT client . Sphero lightning Lab connects to sprk+ when it is brought close to the mobile device. So, I understand the code should use proximity detection profile.

UPDATE : 
Already figured out the solution. If anyone is looking for a Sample - you can check out the code here - https://github.com/tswapnil/PC-controlled-Sphero/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/swapnil/buttondrive

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to a Sprk+ in an Android App using the **beta** branch of the **orbotix/Sphero-Android-SDK** repo.  I belive the **RobotLibrary.jar** in that branch has the necessary updates to interface with a BLE device.  This would allow you to avoid getting into the internals of how BLE works.